# Spring Boot 3 JWT Token Generation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-3, java-21

I'm following this from an article [here](https://github.com/buingoctruong/springboot3-springsecurity6-jwt)

I'm using Spring boot 3 and java 21 to code.

Based on the articles, I only customize the class name from **JwtService** to **CredentialManager**

My version below

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final CredentialManager credentialManager;
    private final UserService userService;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
                                    @NonNull HttpServletResponse response, @NonNull FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String username;

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(authHeader) || !StringUtils.startsWith(authHeader, "Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        username = credentialManager.extractUsername(jwt);

        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(username) && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = userService.userDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (credentialManager.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                context.setAuthentication(authToken);
                SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

the custom configuration file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.requestMatchers("/user/**")
                        .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService.userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(@Lazy  AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

services

```
@Service
public class CredentialManager {

    @Value("${token.secret-key}")
    private String jwtSigningKey;

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
    }

    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String userName = extractUsername(token);
        return (userName.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token);
    }

    private <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolvers) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolvers.apply(claims);
    }

    private String generateToken(Map<String, Object> extraClaims, UserDetails userDetails) {
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(extraClaims).setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 24))
                .signWith(getSigningKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256).compact();
    }

    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getSigningKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Key getSigningKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(jwtSigningKey);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
}
```

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final LoginServiceImpl loginService;
    private final SignUpServiceImpl signUpService;

    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> (UserDetails) userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }

    @Override
    public LoginResponse login(LoginRequest request) {
        return loginService.login(request);
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseBody signUp(SignUpRequest request) {
        return signUpService.signUp(request);
    }
}
```

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LoginServiceImpl {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private final CredentialManager credentialManager;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public LoginResponse login(LoginRequest request) {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.username(), request.password()));
        var user = userRepository.findByUsername(request.username())
                .orElseThrow(() -> {
                    logger.error("Invalid username. Username: {}", request.username());
                    return new BusinessException("Invalid username.");
                });

        var jwt = credentialManager.generateToken((UserDetails) user);
        return new LoginResponse(jwt);
    }
}
```

I'm receiving error message during running the application

```
┌─────┐
|  jwtAuthenticationFilter defined in file [/configuration/JwtAuthenticationFilter.class]
↑     ↓
|  userServiceImpl defined in file [/service/impl/UserServiceImpl.class]
↑     ↓
|  loginServiceImpl defined in file [/service/impl/user/LoginServiceImpl.class]
↑     ↓
|  securityConfiguration defined in file [/configuration/SecurityConfiguration.class]
└─────┘
```

> Action:
> Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.

Anyone can help on this?
Is it because of being initiate multiple times in service classes?

Really appreciate it.

Comment: In your SecurityConfiguration you load the AuthenticationManager with @Lazy. That's usually used because a circular reference is present . \@Lazy loads a proxy until the bean is needed and then tries to find the actually bean. There are two options: redesign you application so that the bean is referenced after creation, or follow the dirty suggestion from the exception: add spring.main.allow-circular-references: true to you application.yml

Comment: Alright, thanks for the explanation @BarbetNL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my offer is use Converter<Jwt, JwtAuthenticationToken> for fill UserDetails and use default flow for token validate OAuth2TokenValidator

Comment: Noted, I have found the tutorial, thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

Add
spring:
main:
allow-circular-references: true
in your application.yml or application.property

Comment: What the heck, never do that! Allowing circular references is the worst thing you can do! If you really get it working while applying this, then the problem ist your own code architecture!